# How to use salt if I am sending hashed password?

Tags: hash, authentication, salt

If have application that is sending username and hashed password to server for authentication, how would I use salt for this scenario ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Ask the server for the salt for a specific username.
2. Compute the expensive salted hash on the client, send to server
3. Server performs a cheap unsalted hash(or HMAC) on the hash received from the client and compares with the stored value

Note that sending a hashed password doesn't mean you can use an insecure transport. You still need proper transport security, such as SSL/TLS/HTTPS or a specialized password verification protocol such as SRP.

Comment: Step 3 is *essential*, do not skip it.

Comment: The secure transport is important, too – otherwise while your password is safe, it actually doesn't protect anything, if the attacker can modify the message's contents.

Comment: For step 1 if username is unrecognized I should send random salt so it is not used for username probing ? Step 3: in database password is stored twice hashed, once with salt and than hash that result once more unsalted ?

Comment: @IvanP 1. If you want to avoid username probing, you can return `HMAC(FakeSaltKey, username)`. A random value isn't possible since for real users the salt will not change often. 3. There is only a single stored value `Hash(SaltedHash(salt, password))`.

Comment: This is unsafe - do not do this. You're just turning the hash into the actual password, and storing a weak hash in the database. You need to use bcrypt on the server side.

Comment: @MarcosPereira Cheap hashes are not a problem is the password is strong enough. It doesn't matter if the hash on the server is weak (as long as it's pre-image resistant), if the strengthening already happened on the client.